# Css 3 Selector not working proberly

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to do something what I thought would be a simple task but it wasnt that quite simple...
the issue in hand can be seen on this 2 links

http://kurdaktuellt.se/

http://kurdaktuellt.se/category/aktuellt/

the selector im using is rather simple

```
body:not(.single) #content > .post:nth-child(odd){
}
body:not(.single) #content > .post:nth-child(even){
}
```

The thing is that it work one way on the front page(first link) and another way on the category page(the second link) it's as it takes a count the header element which it shouldnt if it would follow my selector properly...
Is there something im missing here?

all help is appreciated... aloot!
thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your categories page you have an `h1` as the first child of `#content`, which is interfering with the ordering of your children, causing your first `div.post` to no longer be the first child but really the second child (see the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)).

You can either use `:nth-of-type()` instead so only your `div`s (which have the class `.post`) are taken into account:

```
body:not(.single) #content > div.post:nth-of-type(odd)
body:not(.single) #content > div.post:nth-of-type(even)
```

Or you can choose to modify your HTML instead, either by moving that `h1` elsewhere, or by adding another container around your `div.post` elements, such that your `:nth-child()` ordering won't be messed up.

Comment: didn't have to add the div tag to the selector which is good cause it could be some other element as well... Weird i've always thought that nth-child would only count from the set rule which was .post in this case... You know any good site with a explination to why it's been done this way? Thx for the answer btw saved me alot of time :)

Comment: @Breezer: The reason why I added `div` to the selector is because `:nth-of-type()` doesn't look at the class, it looks at the tag name, and I wanted to make that clear. If you're asking about "why `:nth-child()` behaves this way", it's partly because of how pseudo-classes work and because of how `:nth-child()` is designed. I can't remember any good links off the top of my head, though, but I suppose you can look at [some of my other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A106224+nth-child)...